# Using `Regexp` - how to make list from string array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I have a array which i am getting from back-end server. but i would like to convert that array in to a `list` using 'ul'. How to clean up the array using `regexp` and convert them as a single clear array?

here is the data what i am getting:

```
[
  "1. Submittals in progress\n2. Structural works in progress in S2 & S3\n3. Structural works in progress in N4.\n4. Childrens Mall pedestal and steel fabrication.",
  "",
  "1. Procurement of activities in progress.\n2. External works for mist pool in progress\n3. MEP 1st & 2nd fix in progress\n4. Block work and grade slab in progress "
]
```

the result should be: ( ther is a mark as `\n` for a break. as well `empty` string in between 2 arrays.

```
var array = [
"Procurement of activities in progress.",
"Structural works in progress in S2 & S3",
"Structural works in progress in N4.",
"Childrens Mall pedestal and steel fabrication."
"Procurement of activities in progress."
"External works for mist pool in progress",
"MEP 1st & 2nd fix in progress",
"Block work and grade slab in progress"

]
```

Comment: You have literal `\n` or it is just the newline?

Comment: we can treat this as new line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is input:

```
arr=[
  "1. Submittals in progress\n2. Structural works in progress in S2 & S3\n3. Structural works in progress in N4.\n4. Childrens Mall pedestal and steel fabrication.",
  "",
  "1. Procurement of activities in progress.\n2. External works for mist pool in progress\n3. MEP 1st & 2nd fix in progress\n4. Block work and grade slab in progress "
]
```

You can get your output array using:

```
var array = arr.filter(Boolean).join('\n').replace(/^\d+\.\s+/gm, '').split('\n');
```

`filter(Boolean)` is used to eliminate empty array from input.

**Output:**

```
[
 "Submittals in progress",
 "Structural works in progress in S2 & S3",
 "Structural works in progress in N4.",
 "Childrens Mall pedestal and steel fabrication.",
 "Procurement of activities in progress.",
 "External works for mist pool in progress",
 "MEP 1st & 2nd fix in progress",
 "Block work and grade slab in progress "
]
```

Comment: do you familiar with `angularjs` - because i am using this in `filter`. but when the array have duplicate values, i am getting error. so i tried to use `track by index` - but on the time filter is not working

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You need to

- iterate over the items of first array,
- split each item by new line to create an array,
- concatenate the items to newArray

here is the code

```
var arr1 = [
  "1. Submittals in progress\n2. Structural works in progress in S2 & S3\n3. Structural works in progress in N4.\n4. Childrens Mall pedestal and steel fabrication.",
  "",
  "1. Procurement of activities in progress.\n2. External works for mist pool in progress\n3. MEP 1st & 2nd fix in progress\n4. Block work and grade slab in progress "
];

var newArray = [];
arr1.forEach( function(value){
  if ( value && value.length > 0 )
  {
     value = value.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
     var itemsInArray = value.split("\n");
     if ( value && value.length > 0 && itemsInArray.length > 0 )
     {
       newArray = newArray.concat( itemsInArray );
     }
    }
} );
console.log( newArray );
```

Comment: After concatenate in the array i am seeing that the `index` number repeats . while this all append to html, that will make issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for long Code. use below short & sweet one.

```
var text = [
  "1. Submittals in progress\n2. Structural works in progress in S2 & S3\n3. Structural works in progress in N4.\n4. Childrens Mall pedestal and steel fabrication.",
  "",
  "1. Procurement of activities in progress.\n2. External works for mist pool in progress\n3. MEP 1st & 2nd fix in progress\n4. Block work and grade slab in progress "
]; 
var rawData = text.join('\n').split('\n').filter(function(index) {
    return index !== '' ;
});;
console.log(rawData);
```

I know its not optimized but working.

run this code & watch the output.

Comment: This doesn't remove the numbers, though.

Comment: ohh... not watched the output properly